# How to make response json groupby and get all value of grouped

Tags: sql, json, laravel, laravel-5

How to get data grouped and get all value of data in array

example

```
id name    date       public
1  hi   2018-10-19    true
2  hai  2018-10-20    true
3  bye  2018-10-19    true
```

than i want make response json like

```
data:{
"2018-10-19": [
  {
     "name": "hi",
     "public": true
  },
  {
     "name": "bye",
     "public": true
  }
 ],
 "2018-10-20": [
  {
     "name": "hai",
     "public": true
  }
 ],
}
```

i try this

> $data =  DB::table('calendar')->select('date')->groupBy('date')->orderBy('date','asc')->get();

```
    return response()->json(['status'=>'success','data'=>$data]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user `groupBy` in laravel query:

```
public function calendar($id)
{
  #Calendar is a model name. 
  #data is relationship in Calendar model.

  $calendar = Calendar::whereHas('data', function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('id',$id);
  })->get()->groupBy(column_name_you_want_to_group_by);
    return response()->json([$calendar],200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `groupBy` in laravel collection.

```
// retch the data from the databse as a collection.
$data_collection_from_the_database = ....;

// to group by date
$grouped_collection = $data_collection_from_the_database->groupBy->date;

// to get json
$grouped_collection->toJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = DB::table('calendar')->orderBy('date','asc')->get()->groupBy('date')->toArray();
```